# Relacionar tabla pivot de otro pivot laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, pivot

devs, la `tabla evaluations` **(C)** que es una tabla pivot y que a su vez al relacionarse con la `tabla questions` **(D)** forman otra tabla pivot.
mi duda es al momento de generar las relaciones considero a la tabla C como una tabla principal a la cual le tengo que crear su modelo y relacionarlo con la tabla D ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Evaluations extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

y asi sucesivamente si es que se llega a generar mas tablas pivot de otro pivot? o como es que se maneja las relaciones en este caso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Hola, La tabla pivote "evaluation_question" mayormente yo la desarrollo sin id "identificador, ya que su ID no será consultado nunca, a menos que así lo quieras usar, en el modelo de evaluation haces la función: 
question(){ return $this->belongsToMany(modelo::class,'tabla_pivote'...

Comment: https://styde.net/pivot-tables-con-eloquent-en-laravel/